# In WP7, setting App.Current.RootVisual hides part of the UI behind the system tray

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my SilverLight app, after displaying a loading screen, I show the main screen using

```
App.Current.RootVisual = new MyPage();
```

Part of the UI of the newpage is hidden under the System Tray.

[image: UI partly hidden]

How can I prevent this?

PS: it doesn't happen if I use

```
Uri destination = new Uri("/MyPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(destination);
```

but then users can return to the loading screen by pressing the back button.

Comment: "but then users can return to the loading screen by pressing the back button." : You can remove the loading screen from the backstack using `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();`

Comment: @KooKiz: Thanks a lot for that! It practically solves my problem, though I'd still be interested in knowing where it came from.

Comment: Well, for starters, `RootVisual` is supposed to be a `PhoneApplicationFrame`, not a `PhoneApplicationPage`